# Are photo tags automatically removed when I block someone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I blocked someone about 2 weeks ago and they were tagged in several photos of mine and a mutual friend, let's say person A. When I look at photos with this person through **my account**, there are no longer any tags of the blocked person on my photos and person A's photos.

However, when I logged into a different **mutual friend's account**, let's say person B, the tags of the blocked person only show up on the shared photos of person A and not my own photos.

Basically, has the blocked person removed the tags on my photos?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! And kudos for the great question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you block someone, that person name will disappear from your photos (and your name will disappear from that persons' photos). Here your photos means those photos that originally added by you and tagged by you. If any of your mutual friend have added a photo and tagged that person(whom you have blocked), you will see only that person name but name will no longer link to the person’s Timeline.

**No**, blocked person has not removed the tags on your photos (if blocked person has not removed tags before get blocked). It has just disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

My friend said they block someone from their profile but I can still see that person‘s comment from my page but all the other comments aren’t there anymore just the one